# NoSuchMethodError in javax.persistence.Table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I was using Hibernate 4.3.6 and used annotations based persistence definition. On tomcat 8.0 it was working fine. But when I deployed in WAS Liberty profile 8.5.5.7 it gave the root cause exception as below, and haven't been able to figure out why. Some on told to upgrade Hibernate to 5.1.0 but did not work. I am using Eclipse for development. I am also using Spring 4.0.1.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:936)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:824)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3788)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3742)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1410)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:431)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 57 more
```

Comment: "Somebody told to upgrade" ... well yes, that method is clearly part of JPA 2.1 and you are NOT using consistent versions of JPA provider and JPA jar (and any "it didn't work" means you didn't upgrade correctly). This has been asked many times before on here, all findable using search.

Answer (score 0):

You have an incorrect `jar` in the `WebSphere Liberty` class path, with the `JPA` annotations prior the version 2.1, as 
@NeilStockton suggested.

Firstly, try to add `@Table(indexes = {})` whenever in the source in Eclipse. If it can be imported correctly — you have a correct `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar` (it is for Hibernate 5) in the class path in Eclipse. Delete `@Table(indexes = {})` after that.

To find a `jar` from which incorrect `@Table` annotation is loaded, try to execute this code somewhere independent of the Spring configuration. You can use `ContextListener` for that.

```
URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
    .getResource("javax/persistence/Table.class");
System.out.println(url);
```